# PHP in javascript game development combined

Tags: php, javascript, html, random

Here I have a code:

```
<div id="s">STOP</div>
<div id="L1"></div>
<div id="L2"></div>
<div id="L3"></div>
<div id="L4"></div>
<div id="L5"></div>

v=setInterval(function(){for(i=0;i<6;i++){$("#L"+i).html(String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random()*26+65)))};},500);
$("#s").click(function(){clearInterval(v);});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hx28c/1/

This code give me a random letter when I click on STOP div

NOW I need to get final letter based on php $a...

```
<?php

$a=AGHBV;

?>
<div id="s">STOP</div>
<div id="L1"></div>
<div id="L2"></div>
<div id="L3"></div>
<div id="L4"></div>
<div id="L5"></div>

v=setInterval(function(){for(i=0;i<6;i++){$("#L"+i).html(String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random()*26+65)))};},500);
$("#s").click(function(){clearInterval(v);});
```

so When I click on STOP I need to change content of L1-A , div L2-G, div L3 - H ... ... etc.

How I can do that?

I need this for my game (make the biger word)

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: I need to change random letter as animation but when I click on STOP I need to change content of div based on $a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make the PHP output `$a = "ABCDE"` in the beginning of the JavaScript, such as `echo "\$a=\"abcde\";";`.

Then use the updated script here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hx28c/3/

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as a JSON array, and have it use that on click, instead of just stopping on random letters.

Comment: I need to change random letter as animation but when I click on STOP I need to change content of div based on $a variable... Please HELP me how to do that with JSON...